# Button в windows 10 и в windows 7 отображаются по разному

Tags: wpf

Заметил что в приложении запущенном в windows 10 и в windows 7 кнопки имею разные стили. Как сделать так, что бы кнопки были везде с одним стилем.[скрины прикладываю 1)win7 2)win10]

---

[image: кнопки в windows 7]

[image: кнопки в windows 10]

Comment: Тут даже если тему в одной версии Windows поменять они будут разные, если хотите, чтоб были одинаковыми, то создайте свой шаблон кнопки

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало.